# Trans Pull Subscription Synchronize, Terminates the program after Synchronization

Tags: c#, sql, replication

I have an SQL Data base on my local SQL Server Instance, and I replicate data to another Data Base which is on also on my local SQL Server Express instance .

I use the following code to make the Synchronization operation happen :

```
        // Define server, publication, and database names.
        String subscriberName = Environment.MachineName + "\\SQLEXPRESS";
        // String subscriberName = "(LocalDB)\v11.0";

        String publisherName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PublisherName"].ToString();
        String publicationName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PublicationName"].ToString();
        String publicationDbName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PublicationDbName"].ToString();
        String subscriptionDbName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionDbName"].ToString();

        // Create a connection to the Subscriber.
        ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(subscriberName);
        ServerConnection connPublish = new ServerConnection(publisherName, "sa", "mypassword");
        TransPullSubscription subscription;

        try
        {
            // Connect to the Subscriber.
            conn.Connect();
            // Define subscription properties.
            subscription = new TransPullSubscription();
            subscription.ConnectionContext = conn;
            subscription.DatabaseName = subscriptionDbName;
            subscription.PublisherName = publisherName;
            subscription.PublicationDBName = publicationDbName;
            subscription.PublicationName = publicationName;
            subscription.CreateSyncAgentByDefault = true;

            // If the pull subscription and the job exists, start the agent job.
            if (subscription.LoadProperties() && subscription.AgentJobId != null)
            {
                Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.TransSynchronizationAgent agent = subscription.SynchronizationAgent;
                agent.Synchronize();
            }
            else
            {
                // Do something here if the subscription does not exist.
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(
                    "A subscription to '{0}' does not exists on {1}",
                    publicationName, subscriberName));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ReturnValue = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Disconnect();
        }
```

`

Now my problem is that when the code agent.Synchronize(); runs, the Synchronization operation happens and completes successfully, but the program terminates. I checked the Data base many times and in each times the new values come to the destination DB via Synchronization. But nothing after, Visual Studio Debugger stops as if nothing happened, and leaves me with only this output message :

The program '[13880] MyProgramm.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[13880] MyProgramm.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).

No error,no exception.

Any ideas on why is this happening ?

Comment: I believe the SQL Server management API is using COM, which in turn is native code.  When the native code throws an exception, it kills the .Net Run-Time before it can handle any exceptions.  I've run into this a lot with native extensions that didn't handle errors well.  The best thing I can suggest is see if you can do this through a stored procedure and call that stored procedure.

Comment: Are you expecting the agent to synchronize continuously?

Comment: We finally found the cause of this, though it seems very strange to me .

What is causing this is actually Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack3 . We have tried the same code with SQL 2012 SP1 and SP2, and it worked great . However, when we did update to SP3, this problem started to happen. We had to be sure and even tried in a clean install on a virtual machine and it happened again.

So any ideas on why would SP3 do this ?